# Rewriting a subdomain to this format domain.com/subdomain but subdomain is on another server

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, webserver

The main domain is using Apache and word press.

We've then setup an a record for a subdomain that points to another server which is using nginx / python

My goal is to be able to navigate to

[www.domain.com/community](http://www.domain.com/community)

Rather than the current URL

Community.domain.com

Where do I start with this.

I've read you change it in the htaccess file but won't that only effect the main domain.

Just a push in the right direction would be amazing

Comment: If you try to say that the URL visible in the browser's address bar should always point to the main host ("www.example.com"), then this cannot be done by just rewriting (or redirecting). Instead you need to implement a reverse proxy in the main host (so on the apache http server). But that means a lot of efficiency penalty, since each and every request has to be routed though that frontend server first. And apache is not exactly the fastes proxy server.

Comment: Al alternative would be to just redirect requests to `https://www.example.com/community` to `https://community.example.com`. That allows the first URL to get used _initially_ , but the visible URL actually points to the community server then.

Comment: @arkascha second option is good enough I suppose. Thanks for that. Put it as an answer and I will accept if you wish :)

Comment: Nothing more to be said here. You simply implement that redirection rule. The documentation of the apache rewriting module has some fine examples for that.

Comment: I don't need help with setting that up. I just thought you just might like the accepted answer points.

Comment: Thanks, but no, that is of no importance. I did not answer the question. I only played the role of the yellow rubber duck in this :-)

Comment: My wife will be pleased. Usually she is my rubber duck.